# "file_get_contents" in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, file-get-contents

I want to display a number of a .txt file on my wordpress site via shortcode, I created a function in the functions.php of my theme

funtioncs.php:

```
<?php
[...]
function refresh_visitors()
{
   $visitor = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../uploads/visitors/currentvisits.txt' , true);
   //$visitor = 123;
   return $visitor;
}
add_shortcode( 'visitorcounter', 'refresh_visitors' );
[...]
```

In `currentvisits.txt` is a number e.g. `475`.

For testing I created a `Text block` on my site with the created shortcode.

```
Visitor: [visitorcounter]
```

And... nothing happens.

When I manually set the variable `$visitor` to `123` it appears on my site...

I've just started with Wordpress developing

---

UPDATE:

```
function refresh_visitors(){

global $wp_filesystem;

$file = '/path/to/file/currentvisits.txt';

if ($wp_filesystem->exists($file)) {
    $visitor = $wp_filesystem->get_contents($file);
    //$visitor = "FOUND";
} else {
    $visitor = "NOT FOUND";
}

return $visitor;
}
add_shortcode( 'visitorcount', 'refresh_visitors' );`
```

The `$visitor` variable is still empty ...

Comment: Have you double check the part to make sure it's right using `file_exists`

Comment: Also try not including the file path `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../uploads/visitors/currentvisits.txt' , false);`

Comment: @HuyTrịnh The file exists, but `file_get_contents` still doesn't get the content of the file, maybe it is beacause i've created the function in the funtions.php in my theme?